# What will happen if i change INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS in mysql

Tags: mysql, information-schema

what will happen if i change INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS mysql

I want to change COLUMN_DEFAULT from NULL to '' for whole DB.

will it work?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do will not work, and that's by design.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html says:

> They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on them. Also, there is no database directory with that name.
>
> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database with a USE statement, you can only read the contents of tables, not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.